# Python Image distortion

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to apply a ripple effect to an image in python.
I found Pillow's im.transform(im.size, Image.MESH,.... is it possible? 
Maybe I have to load the image with numpy and apply the algorithm.
I also found this: http://www.pygame.org/project-Water+Ripples-1239-.html

[image: ripple]

another way manually but I don't know any algorithm. this is my start. it doesn't do anything...

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    from PIL import Image
    import sys
    import numpy
    import math

    im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    im.show()

    matrix = numpy.asarray(im)
    width = im.size[0]
    height = im.size[1]
    amplitude = ? # parameters
    frequency = ?
    matrix_dest = numpy.zeros((im.size[0],im.size[1],3))

    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            pass # ç_ç

    im2 = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(matrix_dest))
    im2.show()
```

**EDIT:**

I'd really like to keep this structure (using pillow. I already use extensivly in my project and if I can I wouldn't add any other dependency) and not including scipi or matplotlib..
With the following code I have the distortion I wanted, but **colors** are screwed up.
Maybe I have to apply the distortion to **R,G,B planes** and then compose the result in one image. 
Or **palettize** the image and then apply the original palette.

(Btw the image would be used as a texture to display moving water in a 3D environment.)

```
im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
im.show()

m = numpy.asarray(im)
m2 = numpy.zeros((im.size[0],im.size[1],3))
width = im.size[0]
height = im.size[1]

A = m.shape[0] / 3.0
w = 1.0 / m.shape[1]

shift = lambda x: A * numpy.sin(2.0*numpy.pi*x * w)

for i in range(m.shape[0]):
    print(int(shift(i)))
    m2[:,i] = numpy.roll(m[:,i], int(shift(i)))

im2 = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(m2))
im2.show()
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use `np.roll` to rotate each row or column according to some sine function.

```
from scipy.misc import lena
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = lena()

A = img.shape[0] / 3.0
w = 2.0 / img.shape[1]

shift = lambda x: A * np.sin(2.0*np.pi*x * w)

for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    img[:,i] = np.roll(img[:,i], int(shift(i)))

plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try something like:

```
# import scipy
# import numpy as np
for x in range(cols):
    column = im[:,x]
    y = np.floor(sin(x)*10)+10
    kernel = np.zeros((20,1))
    kernel[y] = 1
    scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve(col,kernel,'nearest')
```

I threw this together just right now, so you'll need to tweak it a bit. The frequency of the sin is definitely too high, check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave). But I think overall this should work.

Comment: Why are the `import` lines commented?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where sometimes the colors appear to be messed up (getting some weird red lines) after applying the sin when attempting the proposed solutions here.  Couldn't resolve it.

I understand the original poster doesn't want more dependencies if possible, but for those unrestricted, here is a an alternative sample solution provided by scikit docs:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_piecewise_affine.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-piecewise-affine-py

Copying from the doc above:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import PiecewiseAffineTransform, warp
from skimage import data


image = data.astronaut()
rows, cols = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]

src_cols = np.linspace(0, cols, 20)
src_rows = np.linspace(0, rows, 10)
src_rows, src_cols = np.meshgrid(src_rows, src_cols)
src = np.dstack([src_cols.flat, src_rows.flat])[0]

# add sinusoidal oscillation to row coordinates
dst_rows = src[:, 1] - np.sin(np.linspace(0, 3 * np.pi, src.shape[0])) * 50
dst_cols = src[:, 0]
dst_rows *= 1.5
dst_rows -= 1.5 * 50
dst = np.vstack([dst_cols, dst_rows]).T


tform = PiecewiseAffineTransform()
tform.estimate(src, dst)

out_rows = image.shape[0] - 1.5 * 50
out_cols = cols
out = warp(image, tform, output_shape=(out_rows, out_cols))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(out)
ax.plot(tform.inverse(src)[:, 0], tform.inverse(src)[:, 1], '.b')
ax.axis((0, out_cols, out_rows, 0))
plt.show()
```